# Updating data type of a column from for loop

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to change data type of a column to integer first then string given that it is a float. I would like to update the data type of column from within a while loop.

The column has a mix of string and float data types.

```
if data_type == str:
            column = column.fillna('') # empty string for NaN values
            index = 0
            for i in column:
                if column == float:
                    column[i] = int(column[i]) 


            return column.astype(str)
```

Comment: Please provide sample of your dataframe and expected output

Comment: The orginal column has a mix of string and floats e.g ['12385, 85020.0, '28593']. Expected output would be I would like to convert everything to string but need to change the float values to integer first

Answer (score 1):

Use [`pandas.to_numeric`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html):

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(['12385', 85020.0, '28593'])
s = pd.to_numeric(s, downcast='integer').astype(str)
```

Output of `s`:

```
0    12385
1    85020
2    28593
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

If some strings have leading 0s that you need to preserve, strip the last `.0`

```
s = pd.Series(['12385', 85020.0, '28593', '000123'])
s.astype(str).str.replace('\.0$', '')

0     12385
1     85020
2     28593
3    000123
Name: col, dtype: object
```

---

This assumes your float values are less than 1e+16, else the replace won't work.